# Reactive programming

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to extract object from Mono then use that object to do other database operation, How to do this without using block()?

like below

```
  Mono<TemplateBo> templateBoMono = 
  templateRepository.findActiveTemplate(tenantId);

    TemplateBo templateBo=
    templateBoMono.flatMap(bo -> {
        bo.setStatus(TemplateStatusEnum.DEACTIVATED);
        return Mono.just(bo);
    }).flatMap(templateRepository::updateTemplate).block();

    templateVersionRepository.findPublishedByTemplateId(templateBo.getId()).flatMap(version -> {
        version.setStatus(TemplateVersionStatusEnum.MODIFIED);
        return Mono.just(version);
    }).flatMap(templateVersionRepository::updateVersion).subscribe();
```

I want to perform both operations at once.

Comment: Please reply its urgent

Comment: Have you read [ask] and [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry for that but I am new here and asking this question was urgent 4 me

Comment: It's OK to be new. It doesn't matter how urgent the question is - a good question gets good answers. Simple as that. I was just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan for the edit

Comment: @AmolKavi – no problem. Adding the tag enabled Java [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), and also, broader visibility on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `block()` and continue `flatmap` your publisher

```
    templateRepository.findActiveTemplate(tenantId)
            .flatMap(bo -> {
                bo.setStatus(TemplateStatusEnum.DEACTIVATED);
                return Mono.just(bo);
            })
            .flatMap(templateRepository::updateTemplate)
            .flatMap(templateBo -> templateVersionRepository.findPublishedByTemplateId(templateBo.getId())
                    .flatMap(version -> {
                        version.setStatus(TemplateVersionStatusEnum.MODIFIED);
                        return Mono.just(version);
                    })
                    .flatMap(templateVersionRepository::updateVersion))
            .subscribe()
```

Comment: note that the `flatMap` for `setStatus` are unnecessary and can be replaced with eg. `.doOnNext(bo -> bo.setStatus(TemplateStatusEnum.DEACTIVATED))`